# Re-writing a join query

Tags: hadoop, hive, left-join, query-optimization

I have a question concerning Hive. Let me explain to you the scenario :

- I am using a Hive action on Oozie; I have a query which is doing
  succesive **LEFT JOIN** on different tables;
- Total number of rows to be inserted is about **35 million**;
- First, the job was crashing due to lack of memory, so I set "***set hive.auto.convert.join=false***" the query was perfectly executed but it took **4 hours** to be done;
- I tried to rewrite the order of LEFT JOINs putting large tables at the end, but same result, about 4 hours to be executed;

Here is what the query look like:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE final_table
SELECT 
T1.Id,
T1.some_field_name,
T1.another_filed_name,

T2.also_another_filed_name,

FROM table1 T1
LEFT JOIN table2 T2 ON ( T2.Id = T1.Id ) -- T2 is the smallest table
LEFT JOIN table3 T3 ON ( T3.Id = T1.Id )
LEFT JOIN table4 T4 ON ( T4.Id = T1.Id ) -- T4 is the biggest table
```

So, knowing the structure of the query is there a way to rewrite it so that I can avoid too many JOINs ?

Thanks in advance

**PS: Even vectorization gave me the same timing**

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, will be deleted later.

**(1)** Your current query won't compile.
**(2)** You are not selecting anything from `T3` and `T4`, which makes no sense.
**(3)** Changing the order of tables is not likely to have any impact with cost based optimizer.
**(4)** Basically I would suggest to collect statistics on the tables, specifically on the `id` columns, but in your case I got a feeling that `id` is not unique in more than 1 table.

Add to your post the result of the following query:

```
select      *
           ,    case when cnt_1 = 0 then 1 else cnt_1 end
            *   case when cnt_2 = 0 then 1 else cnt_2 end
            *   case when cnt_3 = 0 then 1 else cnt_3 end
            *   case when cnt_4 = 0 then 1 else cnt_4 end   as product


from       (select      id
                       ,count(case when tab = 1 then 1 end) as cnt_1
                       ,count(case when tab = 2 then 1 end) as cnt_2
                       ,count(case when tab = 3 then 1 end) as cnt_3
                       ,count(case when tab = 4 then 1 end) as cnt_4

            from       (            select 1 as tab,id from table1
                        union all   select 2 as tab,id from table2  
                        union all   select 3 as tab,id from table3
                        union all   select 4 as tab,id from table4 
                        ) t

            group by    id

            having      greatest (cnt_1,cnt_2,cnt_3,cnt_4) >= 10
            ) t 

order by    product desc

limit       10
;
```